# Datatable doesn't keep the page of updated record

Tags: datatables

I have different record stored in a datatable, suppose I want edit a record on the second page of the datatable, how can I keep the page without go again to the first page?

After the record update, I download again all the records and redraw the datatable:

```
$('#datatable').DataTable().clear().draw(false);
$('#datatable').DataTable().rows.add(updated_records);
$('#datatable').DataTable().draw(false);
```

where `updated_records` are the new records.

As you can see I used `false` as specified [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()), it should keep the page of the `Datable`, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have to enable the [stateSave](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave) in DataTables. It enables the table to save its state of pagination, length, filter and sorting (even on page refresh). It uses the HTML5's APIs `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    stateSave: true
});
```